# Outlook.Application .send() does not send to specified recipients

Tags: outlook, comobject, powershell-7.0

I'm attempting to write a simple powershell script that sends a meeting invite.  It is *creating* the event on my calendar and it throws no errors, but it does not send the invite.

```
function CreateEvents($projectName, $recipient) {
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $NewEvent = $Outlook.CreateItem(1)
    $NewEvent.meetingstatus.olMeeting
    $NewEvent.Subject = "$($projectName) - Phase 1 planning"
    $NewEvent.Body = "This could include anything like links or attachments."
    $NewEvent.Location = 'Executive Conference Room'
    $NewEvent.Start = [datetime]::Today.Adddays(1)
    $NewEvent.Duration = 30
    $NewEvent.Recipients("$($recipient)")
    Write-Host "Sending to $($newEvent.Recipients)"
    $NewEvent.send()
    Write-Host $NewEvent.save()
}

Write-Host "Enter project name: " -NoNewline
[string]$projectName = Read-Host
Write-Host "Enter Receipient: " -NoNewline
[string]$recipient = Read-Host

CreateEvents $projectName $recipient
```

Full output

```
Enter project name:
asdf
Enter Receipient: 
(redacted email)

Application           : System.__ComObject
Class                 : 4
Session               : System.__ComObject
Parent                : System.__ComObject
Address               :
AddressEntry          : System.__ComObject
AutoResponse          :
DisplayType           : 0
EntryID               : (really long ID)
Index                 : 1
MeetingResponseStatus : 0
Name                  : (redacted email)
Resolved              : True
TrackingStatus        : 0
TrackingStatusTime    : 4501-01-01 12:00:00 AM
Type                  : 1
PropertyAccessor      : System.__ComObject
Sendable              : True

Sending to System.__ComObject
```

What am I missing?

---

Update: Current code after adding attendee type and some try/catch blocks:

```
function CreateEvents($projectName, $recipient) {
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $NewEvent = $Outlook.CreateItem(1)
    $NewEvent.meetingstatus.olMeeting
    $NewEvent.Subject = "$($projectName) - Phase 1 planning"
    $NewEvent.Body = "This could include anything like links or attachments."
    $NewEvent.Location = 'Executive Conference Room'
    $NewEvent.Start = [datetime]::Today.Adddays(1)
    $NewEvent.Duration = 30
    $RequiredAttendee = $NewEvent.Recipients.Add($recipient) 
    $RequiredAttendee.Type = 1 
    try {
        $response = $NewEvent.save()
        write-host "Saved"
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Save Error: $($response)"
    }

    try {
        $response = $NewEvent.send()
        write-host "Sent"
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Send Error: $($response)"
    }
}

Write-Host "Enter project name: " -NoNewline
[string]$projectName = Read-Host
Write-Host "Enter Receipient: " -NoNewline
[string]$recipient = Read-Host

CreateEvents $projectName $recipient
```

Console:

```
Enter project name: asfd123
Enter Recipient: (redacted email)
Saved
Sent
```

No email is sent. The event shows up on my calendar and shows the target email in the attendees list, but it does not send anything.  It is not in my sent items. It is not in my outbox. The recipient knows nothing about it.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to setting up recipients of the meeting item you need to set up the [Recipient.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.type) property of each recipient. The [OlMeetingRecipientType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmeetingrecipienttype) lists all possible variants:

```
olOptional  2   Optional attendee

olOrganizer 0   Meeting organizer

olRequired  1   Required attendee

olResource  3   A resource such as a conference room
```

I am not familiar with PowerShell well enough, but the following VBA sample code shows the required sequence of property and method calls to send a meeting request:

```
Sub CreateAppt() 
 Dim myItem As Object 
 Dim myRequiredAttendee, myOptionalAttendee, myResourceAttendee As Outlook.Recipient 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 
 myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting 
 myItem.Subject = "Strategy Meeting" 
 myItem.Location = "Conf Rm All Stars" 
 myItem.Start = #9/24/2009 1:30:00 PM# 
 myItem.Duration = 90 
 Set myRequiredAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myRequiredAttendee.Type = olRequired 
 Set myOptionalAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("User1") 
 myOptionalAttendee.Type = olOptional 
 Set myResourceAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Room1") 
 myResourceAttendee.Type = olResource 
 myItem.Send 
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay now the email address I enter shows up in the attendees list on the event on the source calendar but it never actually sends an invite. The target account has no record of the meeting.

Comment: What is the latest code? Do you have any add-ins running in Outlook? Have you tried handling the `ItemSend` to see whether a meeting request is sent out or not?

Comment: Have you tried handling the `ItemSend` event to see whether a meeting request is sent out or not?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but I included that in my update of the question.  `$NewEvent.send()` is in a try/catch now.  No errors.

Comment: See [Application.ItemSend event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend)

Comment: `Outlook.Application` does not seem to have an `ItemSend` method...

Comment: You are on the wrong avenue. This is an event. To make sure that a meeting request is sent out we need to check out the `ItemSend` event - whether it is fired when you call the send method or not. Your code looks good now. I think other software can intercept requests and delete them.

Comment: Why do you downvote the post? It explains the missed bit. Everything else is fine.

Comment: Ultimately I decided to downvote the answer because the question was about PowerShell and you posted a VBA solution. Additionally, you suggested that the problem was the omission of a Recipient Type. This was not the case.  As for ItemSend, `InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'ItemSend'.`

Comment: It seems your code is working correctly. But there are multiple reasons why the sent request may not reach the required recipient. And I am trying to understand what exactly may cause the issue. The Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages. Your question is about Outlook, not PowerShell. Guys who knows Outlook internals may not be familiar with PowerShell. Do you need to get an answer for PowerShell or solve the problem in Outlook? It is not specific to PowerShell at all...